# Latex: Left alignment for an equation

Tags: latex, alignment

I have these two definitions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
&\boldsymbol{R*^\sigma} & \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')&\\
&\boldsymbol{R*_{weak}^\sigma} & \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')\cap\mathcal{P}(A)&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Compiled, it looks like this: [image]

I want the equations to be aligned by "=" as they are; but also that they are not centered but quite next to the bold symbols. Like, also aligned left.

It should look like this (done with MS Paint): [image: The wanted result]

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: I have now edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that all equations will be left aligned, you could use the `fleqn` option of `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent text

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\boldsymbol{R*^\sigma} & \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')\\
&\boldsymbol{R*_{weak}^\sigma} \quad& \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')\cap\mathcal{P}(A)
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```

If you like to keep other equations centred, you could also switch temporarily:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  a
\]

{
\makeatletter
\@fleqntrue
\makeatother
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&\boldsymbol{R*^\sigma} & \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')\\
&\boldsymbol{R*_{weak}^\sigma} \quad& \sigma_{superset}(F)&=\sigma_{superset}(F')\cap\mathcal{P}(A)
\end{alignat*}
}


\[
  a
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I need other equations (that are in the align environment) to stay or be centered. Putting these in a "center" environment does not work unfortunaly.

Comment: @creative_name I added a second code block which keeps other equations centred

Comment: omg :) thank you very much :))